# Migrations - SequqlizeCLI and/or Umzug with node.js. Difference between using Sequelize CLI and Umzug?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, umzug

I am new to using Sequelize and Umzug with Node.js. I have installed the Sequelize CLI and have tested migrations and seems to work great. I read that umzug is used by some teams to create these migrations. I am not clear on what is the difference between using Sequelize-CLI and Umzug? Pros and cons of each? What is the ideal way to do migrations?

Comment: This was worth asking, and we got as straight, clear, and time-saving answer :-) 
Could *sequelize* docs be improved ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference. Umzug is a JS library. Sequelize-CLI is a command line tool running umzug internally.